# Is it possible to get specific node's children in XML AS3 Flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have xml files with many children and then further more children.

like

```
<level1>
<child id=1 > <nodes....> </child1>
<child id=2 > <nodes....> </child1>
<child id=3 > <nodes....> </child1>
<child id=4 > <nodes....> </child1>
</level1>
```

Is it possible to get the children nodes of child with id = 1 in AS3

Comment: `xml.child.(@id == "3").node.children()` and so on... E4X is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it s possible using [filter](http://joshblog.net/2007/05/08/methods-to-filter-data-with-e4x-in-flash-9/) function on xml:

```
var xml:XML=<level1>
<child id="1" > <nodes>1</nodes> </child>
<child id="2" > <nodes>2</nodes> </child>
<child id="3" > <nodes>3</nodes> </child>
<child id="4" > <nodes>4</nodes> </child>
</level1>;

// list of children with id=1
var xl:XMLList=xml.child.(@id=="1"); //<== here filter xml based on attribute "id"
for each (var node:XML in xl){
  trace(node.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time for a detailed answer right now, but read up on e4x, which allows you to do what you require. I'll try and post an example later.