# (AS3/Flash/AIR) How to get value of complex XML element?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, xml-parsing, air

This sounds simple, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the value of an XML between its tags if it has complex content.

```
<myXML>I want this text</myXML>
  <myChild/>
```

If the XML only had simple content, `xml.toString()` would do exactly what I needed, but since it has a child it is considered complex and the result includes all the tags. How do I get just the element value for a complex XML?

Comment: Some [starting points to research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=as3+xml+child+nodes) while you wait. On the first page I found this [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947977/2057709) which might fix things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xmlText:String;
const textList:XMLList = xml.text();
if (textList.length() > 0) xmlText = textList[0].toString();
else xmlText = "";
```